# Are there certain specific host file entries that Windows 2008 will ignore for security purposes?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hosts-file, ocsp

While troubleshooting a network timeout/connectivity WinHTTP issue, I temporarily added a host file entry for:

```
127.0.0.1 ctldl.windowsupdate.com
```

(The server has no internet connection and the firewall was causing some extended timeouts -- I wanted to temporarily set it to a local address for it to fail immediately).

For some reason though, even after flushing DNS cache, ping attempts still go to the actual IP.

This got me to thinking: Are there certain FQDNs which Windows 2008 absolutely will not acknowledge host file entries for?  Perhaps for malware/virus protection?

Comment: Are you running a through a proxy server>?

Comment: @AliGibbs Nope.  That's the strange part.

Comment: Just tried it on one of my Windows 2008 Servers- exactly the same behaviour- same with www.windowsupdate.com - very strange.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been "known" for quite a few years actually.

if you look in the dnsapi.dll (in system32) you'll see a string of hosts.

There's a

DomainScreenList:

windowsupdate.microsoft.com
windowsupdate.com
microsoftupdate.com
download.microsoft.com
update.microsoft.com

HostsScreenList:

microsoft.com
www.microsoft.com
support.microsoft.com
wustats.microsoft.com
microsoftupdate.microsoft.com
office.microsoft.com
msdn.microsoft.com
go.microsoft.com
msn.com
www.msn.com
msdn.com
www.msdn.com

I don't believe Microsoft ever commented on it, but I guess the intent was to prevent malware and other tools from adding entries to the hosts file.